# Looking to downgrade phpMyAdmin, but don't know what version

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, downgrade

Had to re-set up everything on my laptop recently, which included reinstalling XAMPP.  While I was quite happy with the version of phpMyAdmin I had installed the first time around, the new bundled version has a few quirks that get to me.  Specifically:

- Auto-incremented fields ignore values I enter when inserting new rows (e.g. if I want to create a row with an id of '0' or '-1' for tracking purposes)
- Having the extra drop-menu to tell it to accept the defined default value is an extra hassle, which only compounds if you forget to set it. The previous version I used did this perfectly: If I said the field could be null, it assumed I wanted it null unless I specified a value in the box. I don't put values into the box just so the program can ignore them because I didn't set the menu option.

I asked for help on the phpMyAdmin support forum, but all I got was one short reply justifying the very things that are annoying me.  Can anyone here point me to the version that XAMPP was distributing back around April-May 2009?

Comment: I agree totally with this. I've stopped using phpMyAdmin since they made these "improvements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [XAMPP website](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/news-article,140493.html), looks like the April release bundled phpMyAdmin 3.1.3.1, whereas the latest version includes phpMyAdmin 3.2.0.1.

Hope this helps.